# Two subsets $A$ and $ B$ of the $(x,y)$ plane are said to be $equivalent$ if there exists a function $f:A\to B$ which is both one-to-one and onto.

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Two subsets $A$ and $ B$ of the $(x,y)$ plane are said to be *equivalent* if there exists a function $f:A\to B$ which is both one-to-one and onto.

$(i)$ Show that two line segments in the plane are equivalent.
$(ii)$ Show that any two circles in the plane are equivalent.

My solution goes like this:

> $(i)$ Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be two line segments in the plane. Without loss of generality, assume that $L_1$ and $L_2$ have the same length, and let $P_1Q_1$ and $P_2Q_2$ be the respective endpoints of $L_1$ and $L_2$. Let $f:L_1\to L_2$ be defined by $f(P_1)=P_2$ and $f(Q_1)=Q_2$. Then $f$ is clearly one-to-one and onto, and hence $L_1$ and $L_2$ are equivalent.

Is the  solution for the first part correct? If not, why ? I dont have a clue about how to do the next part...

I struggled a lot with this question and only came to the conclusion that the *equivalent* property as described, is indeed an equivalent relation. But I dont have a clue about what to do next?

Comment: You have not defined $f$ for points between the endpoints. Once that is done, you also have not shown your $f$ is one-to-one and onto. [One more thing: you haven't shown why you may assume the segments have the same length.]

Comment: Hint: show that all line segments are equivalent to $[0,1] \times \{0\}$. And show that all circles are equivalent to the unit circle centred at the origin.

Comment: @coffeemath Your every point is valid. But any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: @coffeemath  Sunil Kumar has provided an answer. I think that seems correct. What do you think ?

Comment: For the different lengths, if the two lengths are $a_1>0$ for $P_1Q_1$ and $a2>0$ for $P_2Q_2$ you could map $P_2Q_2$ into a segment $P_3Q_3$ having length $a_1,$ one way by multiplying each point on $P_2Q_2$ by the constant $(a_1/a_2).$ Then it should be easy to show $P_2Q_2$ is equivalent to $P_3Q_3$ just by checking the suggested map is indeed one to one and onto. this leaves one to do the case where the two segments are of the same length, by using composition of two bijections.

Comment: Sunil Kumar's answer is correct. However you need to show the line sections have a one to one and onto mapping to the real line to show they have the same cardinality. So you might be expected to prove why they have the same cardinality.

Comment: I think Sunil Kumar's approach is oK but it depends on whether the fact cited there is allowed for you to be used.

Comment: @ZoeAllen I think that's true indeed , since, a line section is made of infinite number of points and the set of real numbers is infinite as well, and hence they have a one-to-one correspondence. Correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: That's not quite correct. For example, the set of integers has an infinite number of points, but it isn't in one-to-one correcspondence with the real line. There are different sizes of infinity. You need to show that different line segments are the same size of infinity.

Answer (score 0):

(i) Let $l$ and $m$ be two line segments in $xy$-plane. Let $C$ and $D$ be the set of points lying on line $l$ and $m$ respectively. Then clearly cardinality of both $C$ and $D$ is equal to the cardinality of the set of all real numbers. Hence $C$ and $D$ are equivalent sets.

Comment: Any ideas about part $(ii)$ ?

Comment: Apply the same idea as sets of points corresponding to two circles  will also be uncountable sets.

Comment: @SunilKumar note not every two uncountable sets are equivalent.

Comment: @SunilKumar So for part $(ii)$ you are suggesting this, right ? : Any two circle $C_1$ and $C_2$ is made of infinite points each, and hence they have the same cardinality as the set of all real numbers and thus, each two of the 3 sets (set of points of $C_1$,set of points of $C_2$ , and the set of all real numbers) have a one-one correspondence. Thus, the circles are equivalent.

Comment: @coffeemath I agree that two uncountable set need not be equivalent as   there does not exist largest set. But in this case we can take projection of both circles on x-axis and this will form two intervals. So I am saying this.

Comment: @Sunil Kumar Is my previous comment correct?

Comment: @ Fraklin by just saying that any two circles are made of infinite points we can not say they are equivalent. When we write proof we need to give rigorous reasoning. So apply reasoning of my previous comment when writing proof.

Comment: @SunilKumar I thought again, and for this problem all the sets involved, nontrivial line segments or circles, are subsets of the plane. Since the plane itself is of the cardinality of the continuum, any uncountable subset of it is also of that cardinality.